# Marking fingerprint minutiae - Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fingerprint

I have a project on Fingerprint Matching and I got stuck on marking [minutiae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minutiae).
I have already binarized the image, closed and thinned it and now I have to use Crossing Number to find termination and bifurcation points. How do I mark them on the image and also store them?
Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK crossing number is defined for graphs. How do you represent your binary mask as a graph? please shed some light on this point to make your question clearer.

Comment: Crossing number can be implemented in a 3x3 block by the formula CN=0.5*sum(abs(p(i)-p(i+1))), where p comes from pixel.

Comment: When CN=1, the point is a termination, and when CN=3, the point is a bifurcation

Comment: can you compute `CN` values for all pixels in the mask in an efficient manner?

Comment: The only manner I know is by dividing the image into 3x3 overlapping blocks, though I am not sure how to implement that. I found few ways, including using blockproc function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [`bwmorph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html#inputarg_operation) - a function that allows you to perform all sorts of morphological operations on images.

```
ep = bwmorph( BW, 'endpoints' ); %// returns a mask with the "terminations"
bp = bwmorph( BW, 'branchpoints' ); %// returns a mask with "bifurcations"
```

To get the coordinates of the special points from the masks, you can simply use `find`:

```
[epy epx] = find( ep ); %// x,y coordinates of all endpoints.
```

Comment: It is helpful, but I need to implement the operations with Crossing Number. Built-in functions are the last resort.

Answer (score -1):

I normally use frequency transforms to get the minutiae.
Maybe try this algorithm :  ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/4263198/4263199/04263211.pdf?arnumber=4263211
or there's code in matlab you can look at: https://www.mathworks.com/.../44369-fingerprint-matching--a-simple-approach

Comment: The link to mathworks is broken and the link to IEEE requires us to sign-in. Can you provide the details from the links to help us understand what algorithm you are referring to please.

Comment: Sorry this answer was provided 5 years ago. Therefore, the link is taking down which was out of my control. I may have to look into it, to provide more information and update the answer. Please be patience on this, since I am no longer in the biometric image processing field.

Comment: If you use morphological you will have a problem with accuracy. Please use this as a starting point https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1105720/FULLTEXT01.pdf while I get the code I was referring to.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Will look into the new link.